# Find $MAX$ and $MIN$ of $P = 2ab+3ac+3bc+\frac{6}{a+b+c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima

Let : $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ , $a\ge 0 , b\ge 0,0\le c\le 1 $ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

Find $MAX$ and $MIN$ of $P=2ab+3ac+3bc+\dfrac{6}{a+b+c}$.

Comment: I want to have an element solution use classical inequalities? Can you help me ?

Comment: change variables to uncouple. For example $x=a+b$, $y=ab$ and $z=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Lagrange multiplier, but you will have to add 5 conditions, the inequalities will become equalities, so that will give $2^4=32$ cases to check. This is actually application of the [KKT conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) Although some of them will cancel, because of contradiction. The function is:

$$f(a,b,c) = 2ab + 3ac + 3bc + \frac{6}{a+b+c}$$

After applying Lagrange Multiplier we have:

$$F(a,b,c,\lambda,\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4) = 2ab + 3ac + 3bc + \frac{6}{a+b+c} - \lambda(a) - \lambda_1(b) - \lambda_2(c) + \lambda_3(c-1) + \lambda_4(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 3)$$

Now we take partial derivatives:

$$F_a = 2b + 3c -\frac{6}{(a+b+c)^2} - \lambda + 2\lambda_4a= 0$$ 
$$F_b = 2a + 3c -\frac{6}{(a+b+c)^2} - \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_4b= 0$$ 
$$F_c = 3a + 3b -\frac{6}{(a+b+c)^2} - \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + 2\lambda_4c= 0$$

We know that those $\lambda$ terms has to be set to 0, so we have $16$ distinct cases.

**Case 1: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$**

**Case 2: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = c-1 = 0$**

**Case 3: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = c = \lambda_3 = 0$**

This one is violates the condition: $0<c$

**Case 4: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = c = c-1 = 0$**

This is a contradiction.

**Case 5: $\lambda = b = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$**

**Case 6: $\lambda = b = \lambda_2 = c-1 = 0$**

This implies a solution $(a,b,c) = (\sqrt{2},0,1)$

**Case 7: $\lambda = b = c = \lambda_3 = 0$**

This one is violates the condition: $0<c$

**Case 8: $\lambda = b = c = c-1 = 0$**

This is a contradiction.

**Case 9: $a = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$**

**Case 10: $a = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = c-1 = 0$**

This implies a solution $(a,b,c) = (0,\sqrt{2},1)$

**Case 11: $a = \lambda_1 = c = \lambda_3 = 0$**

This one is violates the condition: $0<c$

**Case 12: $a = \lambda_1 = c = c-1 = 0$**

This is a contradiction.

**Case 13: $a = b = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$**

This implies a solution $(a,b,c) = (0,0,\sqrt{3})$, but this violates the condition $c\le1$

**Case 14: $a = b = \lambda_2 = c-1 = 0$**

This implies a solution $(a,b,c) = (0,0,1)$, this implies the condition $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3$

**Case 15: $a = b = c = \lambda_3 = 0$**

This one is violates the condition: $0<c$

**Case 16: $a = b = c = c-1 = 0$**

This is a contradiction.

Now as you can see we excluded many cases, and i solved some that are easier, now you can play with the other $3-4$ cases using the partial derivatives.

Now plug all those solutions into the initial function and see which one is minima and which one is maxima.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The minimum is $2\sqrt 3$ when $a = b = 0$ and $c = \sqrt 3$.

**Proof**.

Let $x = a + b + c$.
Using $a + b + c \le \sqrt{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)} = 3$ and $a + b + c \ge \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = \sqrt 3$, we have $x \in [\sqrt 3, 3]$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 2ab + 3ac + 3bc + \frac{6}{a+b+c}
 &\ge 2ab + 2ac + 2ab + \frac{6}{a + b + c}\\
 &= (a + b + c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + \frac{6}{a + b + c}\\
 &= x^2 + \frac{6}{x} - 3\\
 &\ge 2\sqrt 3
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that $x \mapsto x^2 + \frac{6}{x} - 3$ is strictly increasing on $[\sqrt 3, 3]$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

(2) The maximum is $10$ when $a = b = c = 1$.

**Proof**.

We have
$$2ab + 2bc + 2ca \le 2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2c^2 = 6. \tag{1}$$

If $a + b + c \ge 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 ac + bc + \frac{6}{a + b + c}
 &= ac + bc + \frac{6 - 2(a + b + c)}{a + b + c} + 2\\[6pt]
 &\le ac + bc + \frac{6 - 2(a + b + c)}{2} + 2\\[6pt]
 &= 4 - (1 - c)(a + b - 1)\\
 &\le 4 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where we use $a + b + c \le \sqrt{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)} = 3$ and
$c \le 1$ and $a + b \ge \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{3 - c^2} \ge \sqrt 2$.

If $a + b + c < 2$, we have
$$ac + bc + \frac{6}{a + b + c}
\le (2 - c)c + \frac{6}{\sqrt 3}
\le \frac12 + 2\sqrt 3 < 4 \tag{3}$$
where we use
$(2 - c)^2 > (a + b)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2 = 3 - c^2$
to obtain $2c - c^2 \le 1/2$;
and $a + b + c \ge \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = \sqrt 3$.

From (1), (2) and (3), we have
$$2ab + 3ac + 3bc + \frac{6}{a+b+c} = (2ab + 2bc + 2ca) + \left(ac + bc + \frac{6}{a + b + c}\right) \le 10.$$

We are done.