# Find the minimum value of $P=ab+bc+3ca+\dfrac{3}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Find the minimum value of $$P=ab+bc+3ca+\dfrac{3}{a+b+c}.$$
This is an asymmetric inequality. It is hard for me to find when the equation holds. I guess when it occurs if $a=c=0$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$. Then $\min P=\sqrt{3}$. But I have no idea to solve it. Please help me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: A simiilar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514695/find-max-and-min-of-p-2ab3ac3bc-frac6abc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $a,c \ge 0$ then
$$P \ge S := ab+bc+ca + \frac{3}{a+b+c}$$

We minimize $S$

As $a^2+b^2 +c^2 = 3$ then
$$S =\frac{1}{2} (a+b+c)^2+\frac{3}{a+b+c} -\frac{3}{2}$$
Denote $x = a+b+c$. Because $a^2+b^2 +c^2 = 3$ then $\sqrt{3} \le x \le 3$
$$S = f(x) := \frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{3}{2}$$
As $f'(x) = x-\frac{3}{x^2}>0$ in the interval $[\sqrt{3},3]$ then $f(x)$ is increasing. Hence, $S_1 = f(x)$ is minimized as $a+b+c = x_0 = \sqrt{3}$

**Conclusion:** we can conclude that
$$P \ge  S \ge \sqrt{3} $$
The equality occurs when $(a,b,c) = (0,\sqrt{3},0),(0,0,\sqrt{3})$ or $(\sqrt{3},0,0)$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is simpler than what I think it has to.

Comment: @VichLee You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, by simply calculating one has $P(\sqrt 3, 0, 0) = \sqrt 3$. On the other hand,

> We know a minimum must exist by Weierstrass's theorem. This is because $Z := \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb R ^3\mid a, b, c \geq 0, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3\}$ is a closed bounded set and $P$ is continuous on $Z$.

Write $$P(a,b,c) = S_1 + S_2 \tag{1}$$

where $S_1 :=ab + bc + \dfrac{3}{2} + ac + \dfrac{3}{a + b + c}$ and $S_2 :=2ac - \dfrac{3}{2}$. Note that $S_1$ is symmetric. The choice of $\dfrac{3}{2}$ will be clear should you read on.

> If it is possible to simultaneously minimise $S_1$ and $S_2$ (with given constraints), then their sum will be the minimum value of $P$. Let us try to minimise $S_1$.

Plugging $bc = \dfrac{1}{2}(b+c)^2 - \dfrac{3}{2} + \dfrac{a^2}{2}$ into $S_1$ yields
$$ S_1 = \dfrac{1}{2}(b+c)^2 + (b + c) a + \frac{3}{(b + c) + a} + \dfrac{a^2}{2},$$

or with $x := b + c$,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
S_1(x, a) &= \dfrac{1}{2} x^2 + a\, x + \frac{3}{x + a} + \dfrac{a^2}{2} = \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} (x + a)^2 + \dfrac{3}{x + a} = \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} z^2 + \dfrac{3}{z}.
\end{split}
\tag{2}
\end{align}

- We are left with the problem of minimising $S_1(z)$ wrt $z$ when $z \geq \sqrt 3$ (because $z^2 \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$).
- The derivative with respect to $z$ is $z - \dfrac{3}{z^2}$. This is positive if $z > \sqrt[3]{3}$. So $S_1$ is increasing for $z \geq \sqrt[3]{3}$ and we should pick $z_0 := \sqrt 3$ if we can (choosing $z_0 := \sqrt[3]{3}$ is not possible because $\sqrt[3]{3} < \sqrt 3$).

If one moves up the chain, we have $z_0 = x_0 + a_0 = a_0 + b_0 + c_0 = \sqrt 3$. And we see it is possible to choose $a_0 := \sqrt 3$ and $b_0 := c_0 := 0$ to obtain $z_0 = \sqrt 3$, thus minimising $S_1$. By picking $c_0 = 0$, $S_2$ is minimised as well, so we are done. In conclusion, the minimum value of $P$, subject to given constraints, is $\sqrt 3$. It is obtained at, for example, $(a_0, b_0, c_0) = (\sqrt 3, 0, 0)$.

Comment: No, the second term is minimized when $a=b=c=1$

Comment: @NN2 Hopefully, the answer has now improved.

Comment: I read until this equation and I stop because this equation
$$ (b + c) + (b + c)\alpha + \frac{3}{(b + c) + 1 + \alpha}$$
is false. You forgot at least the factor $3$ of $3ac$

Comment: @NN2 I partitioned $P$ into $S_1$ and $S_2$ to get rid of said factor.

Comment: Ok, I see. The answer seems to be correct now.

Comment: Ah. You were correct nonetheless... apparently, I omitted $bc$. I'll have to think about it again.

Comment: No, you don't need to consider the case $bc$. In fact, it suffices to minimize $S_1$ as you did. And the equality is when 2 numbers among $(a,b,c)$ are equal to $0$. And the second term $S_2 \ge 0$ (and of course, the condition that $S_1$  is minimized satisfies the condition of that $S_2 = 0$

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I defined $S_1$ incorrectly. The solution after that forgets about $bc$ being there. And if I took $bc$ instead into $S_2$, the partition is no longer symmetric.

Comment: I don't know why you said you defined $S_1$ incorrectly. In fact, $$S_1 =ac + bc + ac + \dfrac{3}{a + b + c}$$ is symmetric and you proved that $$S_1 \ge \sqrt{3} \tag{1}$$ The equality occurs when 2 values among $a,b,c$ are equal to $0$. And it's easy to see that $$S_2 \ge 0 \tag{2}$$ From $(1),(2)$ you deduce $P = S_1+S_2 \ge  \sqrt{3} \tag{3}$
and the equality of $(3)$ occurs when 2 values among $a,b,c$ are equal to $0$

Comment: It should have been $ab + bc + ac + \ldots$ and when I plugged in $a = 1 + \alpha$, I accidentally omitted the term $bc$.

Comment: @NN2 I fixed my answer after a good night's sleep. But I see in the meantime you uploaded your answer (+1) which I think is more clear.